# Is there a preset 'index' or something similar that allows me to refer to specific annotations that a user created? Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I have an app where the user can search for locations, tap on the row in the table view, and an annotation will be placed at the placemark.  I have a button, "meetUpButton" that allows them to put multiple annotations, rather than what my code does by default which is remove the annotation if a new search result is clicked.  Is there a way to refer to a specific annotation that my user created, even if they made multiple?  For example, say I want to add the latitude of two annotations that my user created...
If I have

```
let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
annotation.coordinate.latitude
```

Is there a way to refer to something like the first annotation with an index of 0 and the next one that my user chose with a 1 or another way? Here's some of my code which might make this clearer.

```
extension ViewController: handleMapSearch {
func dropPinZoomIn(placemark:MKPlacemark) {
    resultSearchController?.isActive = false

    // cache the pin
    selectedPin = placemark
    // clear existing pins
    if meetUpOutlet.isEnabled == true {

        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)

    } else {

    }

    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

    annotation.coordinate = placemark.coordinate
    annotation.title = placemark.name
    if let city = placemark.locality,
        let state = placemark.administrativeArea {
        annotation.subtitle = "(\(city)) (\(state))"
    }
    mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(placemark.coordinate, span)
    mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
}
```

Comment: let myPin = mapView.annotations[0];mapView.selectAnnotation(myPin, animated: true)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `annotations` property of `MKMapView` instance , to get all use

```
let anns = self.mapView.annotations
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement Custom annotation class.

e.g.

```
class MyAnnotation : NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var index: Int?

    init(location coord:CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coord
        super.init()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
    let annotation = MyAnnotation(location: coordinate)
    annotation.title = "title"
    annotation.subtitle = "subtitle"
    annotation.index = 1
```

Remove annotations (only index == 1)

```
    for annotation in self.mapView.annotations {
        guard let annotation = annotation as? MyAnnotation else {
            continue
        }
        if annotation.index == 1 {
            self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }
```